# Mailgun - POST body is not interpreted as url-encoded

Tags: http, https, http-post, mailgun

I'm trying to send emails through mailgun email service. I'm using angular 2. This is what my service looks like:

```
  sendEmail(fromName, fromEmail, message) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    var recieverMail = "abc@123.se";//service@csc.kth.se"
    var subject = "error report submitted by interactive screen"
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa("MY_API_KEY"));
    headers.append("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mymailgun.mailgun.org/messages";
    var data = "from="+fromName+"&to=" +recieverMail+"&subject="+subject+"&text="+message;
    return this.http.post(url,data, {headers: headers});
  }
```

I got two different programs that is using this service and they both passes the service strings but the service only fails for one of them.

Applcation 1 recieves an error message saying that the "from" parameter is missing and it is because the mail data is not interpreted as url-encoded for some reason. It is just interpreted as plain text!

[image]

Application 2 successfully sends messages with the same service and input. As you can see, this time the mail data is interpreted as url-encoded and the mailgun API recognizes the mail parameters.

[image]

Any suggestions on what might be causing this problem for application 1?

(I know that the data is not 100% identical from the screenshot but the problem that i want to illustrate is that they interpret the mail data differently)